# Calculus 2: Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region under the curve y = 9 / x

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

I solved the following problem but my answer does not match the textbook answer.

```
Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region under the curve y=9/x, from x = 1 to x = Q, about the x-axis.
```

Below is my work:

[image]

Is my answer correct?

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: Are you sure about the limits of integration? That curve is not defined at $x=0$.